# assigning model names to gbm.step in loop in r

Tags: r, gbm

I'm trying to run gbm.step in a loop with multiple learning rates.
i would like to get models named gbmModel.i for all i.

Can anyone suggest how to go about doing it

Following is the code:

```
learningRateList <- as.numeric(8:10)*0.01

for (i in learningRateList){
  gbmModel.i<-gbm.step(data=train, gbm.x = reqCol, gbm.y = CloseCol,tree.complexity =9,learning.rate = i,bag.fraction = 0.75,family =     "laplace",step.size=100 )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
learningRateList <- as.numeric(8:10)*0.01
for (i in learningRateList){
  nam <- paste("gbmModel", i, sep = ".") 
  models <-gbm.step(data=train, gbm.x = reqCol, gbm.y = CloseCol,tree.complexity =9,learning.rate = i,bag.fraction = 0.75,family =     "laplace",step.size=100 )
  assign(nam, models)

  #  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To store your models as individual objects, one approach would be to paste together the model name and the value of the iteration i, and then assign the model to it.

```
learningRateList <- as.numeric(8:10)*0.01
for(i in learningRateList){
    assign(paste0("gbmModel.",i)) <- gbm.step(data=train, gbm.x = reqCol, 
      gbm.y = CloseCol, tree.complexity =9, learning.rate = i,
      bag.fraction = 0.75,family = "laplace",step.size=100)
}
```